# awk capability cut capability

Tags: awk, grep, cut

I am using the following ssh command to get a list of ids.  Now I want to

1. get only ids greater than a given number in the list of ids; let's say "231219" in this case. How can I incorporate that?
2. I have a local file "ids_ignore.txt"; anyid we put in this list should be ignored by the command..

Can awk or cut do the above?

```
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit query --commit-message --files --current-patch-set \
    status:open project:platform/code branch:master |
grep refs | cut -f4 -d'/'
```

OUTPUT:-

```
231222
231221
231220
231219
230084
229092
228673
228635
227877
227759
226138
226118
225817
225815
225246
223554
223527
223452
223447
226137
```

Comment: You question isn't clear, add the output from the `ssh` command.

Comment: @sudo_O - output of ssh command is already given

Comment: If that is the output from the ssh command then why are you grepping for `refs` and cutting as it's a list of digits? I believe what you have posted is your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
... | awk '$1 > max' max=8888 | grep -v -F -f ids_ignore.txt
```

Or, if you want to do it all with awk:

```
 ... | awk 'NR==FNR{ no[$1]++ } 
        NR!=FNR && $1 > max && ! no[$1]' max=NNN ids_ignore.txt -
```

Comment: I still see the ids being printed by the ssh command even for the ones in ids_ignore.txt

Comment: I treid both the above ways..still I see the numbers presen in ids_ignore.txt is beign printed

Answer (score 0):

`cut` cannot do numeric comparison on the input fields, it's just a simple field extraction tool. `awk` can do the work of grep and cut:

```
ssh -p 29418 company.com gerrit ... |
awk -F/ -v min=231219 '
    NR == FNR {ignore[$1]; next} 
    /refs/ && $4>min && !($4 in ignore) {print $4}
' ids_ignore.txt -
```

The trailing <kbd>-</kbd> is important at the end of the awk command: it tells awk to read from stdin after it reads the ids_ignore file.